# How to populate additive field via JOIN with Doctrine

Tags: php, mysql, join, doctrine-orm, field

Suppose i have an entity with a ManyToOne relation (with EXTRA_LAZY) and obviously a join column.

```
eg. Article (main entity) -> Author (external entity)
```

suppose i add  a field `author_name` to the Article that NOT mapped to the ORM and that in certain contexts this field should contain the `article->author->name` value (usually it can stay null).

When i query a list of articles, i would like to populate automatically that article-author_name without implementing a getter that perform a select on each element of the query result. I would like Doctrine to fetch and hydrate that value in with a simple JOIN in the original query...

I don't want to set fetch mode to EAGER for performance as in my project Author is a really complex entity.

Is this possible?

Thanks

Comment: I checked all Doctrine annotations today and haven't found any which would allow you to do that.

Answer (score 0):

Probably i've found a solution. Don't know if it is the best way to do it but it works.

I've added to the main class a field getter

```
public getAuthorName() {
  return $this->author->name
}
```

in my context this getter will only be called by a serializer in certain conditions.

In my repository code i have a special method (that i refactored so that any method could implicitly call it) to impose the population of the Article->author field when queried. The method simply use the querybuilder to add LEFT JOIN to the Author class and temporarily set FetchMode to EAGER on Article->author.

At the end a simple repository method could be this

```
public findAllWithCustomHydration() {
    $qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('obj');
    $qb->leftJoin("obj.author", "a")
       -> addSelect("a"); //add a left join and a select so the query automatically retrive all needed values to populate Article and Author entities
    //you can chain left join for nested entities like the following
    //->leftJoin("a.address", "a_address")
    //-> addSelect("a_address");


    $q = $qb->getQuery()
              ->setFetchMode(Article::class, "author", ClassMetadata::FETCH_EAGER);
   //setFetchMode + EAGER tells Doctrine to prepopulate the entites NOW and not when the getter of  $article->author is called. 
   //I don't think that line is strictly required because Doctrine could populate it at later time from the same query result or maybe doctrine automatically set the field as EAGER fetch when a LEFT JOIN is included in the query, but i've not yet tested my code without this line.

    return $q->getResult();
}
```

The con is that you have to customize each query or better use a DQL / SQL / QueryBuilder for each method of the repo but with a good refactoring, for simple inclusion cases, you can write a generic method that inject that join on a field_name array basis.

Hope this help and add your answer if you find a better way.

PS. i've wrote the above code on the fly because now i'm not on my notebook, hope it works at first execution.